# how make directory for user when register in php class

Tags: php

Hi i want to make directory for user when they sign up i know the simple way in Mysql but i want it to work with my user class:

right know its work in simple php code like this:

```
if(!file_exists("user/$username"){
     mkdir("user/$username");
 }
```

but i want to add this code to this class:

```
<?php
      //this class is for signup user
       class User{
         //we need private property for our connection
   private $_db,
           $_data,
           $_sessionName,
           $_cookieName,
           $_isLoggedIn;

    //method for construct new user
    public function __construct($user = NULL)
   {
   //get user connection
   $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
   //get user session
   $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
   //get user cookie
   $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

   //here we check to see if user logged in or not
   //so if currect user not
   if (!$user) {
     //if session exists
     if (Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
       //get user session
       $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);
       //and if every thing is correct we loggedin user
       if ($this->find($user)) {
          $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
       }else {
         # code...
       }
     }
   }else {
     //if user not loggedin we find info of user
     $this->find($user);
   }

    }
  //create method for create new user and it has array of fields
  public function create($fields = array())
  {
   //using insert method from class DB($table,$fields)
   if (!$this->_db->insert('users',$fields) {
     throw new Exception("There was Problem Creating an Account");
   }

  }

 //method for login
 public function login($username = NULL,$password=NULL,$remember=false)
 {

 //chech for is username or password is not defined but we are login as
 //remeber me so its login automatic
 //here this exists means this user exists
    if (!$username && !$password && $this->exists()) {
     //so now that we have that user
     //we create session automatic so name and value
     Session::put($this->_sessionName , $this->data()->id);
     }else {
         $user = $this->find($username);

    if ($user) {
      //here we say if password that user insert is = to hash password
      //in table
 if ($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password,$this->data()->salt))             
      {    Session::put($this->_sessionName,$this->data()->id);
   //checking for remeber me functionlaity
       if ($remember) {
         //first we take uniqid from Hash class
            $hash = Hash::unique();
            //we get data from user_session table ,
            //and set user_id to id of currect user
            $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session',
                                    array('user_id','=',$this->data()->id));
            //now if inside our users_session hashCheck has no value
            if (!$hashCheck->count()) {
              //we insert
              $this->_db->insert('users_session',array(
                'user_id' => $this->data()->id ,
                'hash' => $hash
              ));
            }else {
              //else we get first hash from user_session table
              $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
            }
            Cookie::put($this->_cookieName,$hash,
                        Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
       }

       return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
  }
   }
 //method for find user and the reason we say user is
 //because we want to find user not by only username but also by ID
 public function find($user = NULL)
 {
   if ($user) {
     //now if it was numeric we find it by id otherwise by username
     $field = (is_numeric($user))? 'id' : 'username';
     //declare data which is data from column of user table
     $data = $this->_db->get('users',array($field,'=',$user));

     if ($data->count()) {
        $this->_data = $data->first();
        return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
  }

   //method for logout user
   public function logout()
   {
     //for remove hash from DB
     $this->_db->delete('users_session',array(
       'user_id', '=' , $this->data()->id
     ));
    //delete session
   Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
   //delete cookie for remeber
   Cookie::delete($this->_cookieName);
   }
 //method for update user name
 public function update($fields = array(),$id = NULL)
   {
   //here we declare if id is not declare and we are loggedin
   if (!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
     //we get id
      $id = $this->data()->id;
   }
    //we use update method from DB class
   if (!$this->_db->update('users',$id,$fields)) {
        throw new Exception("there was problem updating");

   }
     }
  //method for cehck permission to see if we user admin or simple user
 //  public function hasPermission($key)
 //  {
 //    //first we check to see id of group
 //     $group = $this->_db->get('groups',array(
 //       'id','=',$this->data()->group
 //     ));
 //     //then if we have any data
 //     if ($group->count()) {
 //       //we decode json permissions becuase our data is json and we
 //       //get first permissions
 //        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions,true);
 //         //then if our key is true we return true
 //        if ($permissions[$key] == true) {
 //          return true;
 //        }
 //     }
 //     return false;
 //  }

 //method for return data property from users
 public function data()
 {
   return $this->_data;
 }
 //method for return isLoggedIn property
 public function isLoggedIn()
 {
   return $this->_isLoggedIn;
 }
 //method for check if data is exists
 public function exists()
 {
   return (!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
 }

  }


       ?>
```

i'm sorry if its too long but i could find answer here so i prefer to post it by my self

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? Take the PHP code for making the folder, and put it in the class.

Comment: this is the class for when user register and also it has login method and logout method and its work great but because i want to each user has his own directory for example for they profile photo i cant mix the first code with this class  do you know solution?

Comment: Why can't you mix the two? Isn't username unique? Then make the directory on the class, on either first login or when creating the user.